# Determining types with generics

Tags: c#

The following program outputs "We have something else". How do I properly determine a DataType of the type being passed in?

```
void Main()
{
    AFunction(typeof(string));
}

void AFunction<T>(T aType) {

    if (aType.GetType() == typeof(string)) {

        Console.WriteLine ("We have a string");

    } else {
        Console.WriteLine ("We have something else");
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, exactly?  Do you want `We have a string` to be printed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `is` keyword.

```
if(aType is string)
    Console.WriteLine("We have a string");
else
    Console.WriteLine("We have something else");
```

One thing to note when using this kind of logic is that `is` will return true for super-types which could lead to unexpected behavior:

```
if(myObj is object)
    Console.WriteLine("This will always print");
else if(myObj is int)
    Console.WriteLine("This will never print");
```

Comment: In your example, you're passing in a `Type` not a `string` which is why it "isn't working."

Comment: @Vince: in other words, `aType.GetType() is string` is the wrong construct. It should be `aType is string` as Wesley has.

Answer (score 2):

if you're looking for type from a (small) finite list, you can use 'is'.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to use Generic Type in this circumstance.
You just send an Object Type to the AFunction and then use the `is` keyword as follows:

```
void AFunction(Object aType) 
{ 
     if (aType is string) { 

        Console.WriteLine ("We have a string"); 

    } else { 
        Console.WriteLine ("We have something else"); 
    } 
}
```

By the way, I think that the Generic Type is not for this kind of usage.

Answer (score 0):

`typeof(string)` returns a `Type`.

So the compiler infers that you mean to call `AFunction<Type>(typeof(string))`.

`GetType` returns a `Type` that represents the type `Type` for an instance of `Type`.

`typeof(Type)` does not equal `typeof(string)`, so the result is exactly as expected.

---

Did you mean

```
AFunction<string>("Hello World");

void AFunction<T>(T value)
{
    if (value is string) ...
}
```

or

```
AFunction(typeof(string));

void AFunction(Type type)
{
    if (type == typeof(string)) ...
}
```

or

```
AFunction<string>();

void AFunction<T>()
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(string)) ...
}
```

?

Comment: No I want to determine the type of aType

Comment: @Vince: The type of `Type` is `Type`. `typeof(string).GetType() == typeof(Type)`

Comment: "The type of Type is Type" LOL ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using your current calls you could make AFunction something like this:

```
void AFunction<T>(T aType)
{
    if ((aType as Type).Name == "String")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("We have a string");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("We have something else");
    }
}
```